# Can i install Flash player "Pepper" on Chromium with automatic updates?

Tags: flash

If I follow [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-pepper-flash-player-for.html) guide , will the flash version be automatically updated? or will I need to manually update this API with any new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a PPA. Like any other PPA, updates delivered through the PPA depends on the owner of the PPA providing those updates, and in a timely manner. There is no guarantee of proper and timely security updates via that PPA. However, as long as the owner of the PPA continues to update the package properly, then it will be updated whenever you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.